# KeyChain security vs hash-salting mechanism, which is better?

Tags: ios, authentication, hash, offline, keychain

Developing an enterprise iOS 7 mobile application, currently the user gets authenticated using his credentials (username and password) to dedicated Server.

But we need to provide offline authentication as well, as network connectivity is a major issue.

So one way is:

1. For the very first login time, the user must be in online mode
2. The user gets authenticated.
3. Cache the password hashes in iOS app
4. If offline mode verify with the hash.

Is this approach fine? OR

- Just utilize iOS Keychain functionality to store the password is better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the KeyChain. It is a bit more difficult than storing it in your App folder but it is a lot more secure.

The KeyChain will handle all of the encryption for you and will provide you with options on what will happen to your data when the device is restored  and place conditions on when the data is accessible (e.g only for unlocked devices).

If you're developing more than one app you can use the KeyChain to share information between apps. One thing to keep in mind is that the KeyChain retains information even after app removal, unless you remove it.

An easy way to get started is to use CocoaPods in your project and do a search for KeyChain pods.

One question to you: do you really need to re-authenticate (offline) after the first login? If you do it might be more userfriendly to ask for a pin (which you can store in the KeyChain).

Comment: pin -- do you mean to say hash of password?

Comment: After your first (online) authenticate you could store a token for further communication with the server. I guess you want some added security by having the user authenticate every session. Instead of asking them for their password every time you could ask them to create a 4 or 5 number pin (store that in the keychain and ask that at startup). Then you don't have to hash their password and compare it offline.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the information if the app is not secture because if someone wants to hack your app there are ways to see the contents of the app package on the device. For example saving inforamation in file created programmatically will turn into creating a file if the /Documents directory of your app. As for Keychain:

> Keychains are secure storage containers, which means that when the keychain is locked, no >one can access its protected contents.

From the offical Apple documetation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html

So it's more secure to use Keychain